# add new field and data with php to json encoded object with quotes removed

Tags: php, json

I converted php array to json and I try to add another field and data with quotes removed.
this is json object generated

```
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

It outputs this .

```
{"dateDebut":"36000000","dateFin":"45000000","periodeDebut":"1410818400","periodeFin":"1411596000","jours":"Thursday","role":{"idRole":"1"},"zone":{"idzone":"Z1E2"},"tag":{"id":"511651969251"},"typeNotification":{"typeNotif":"Alerte"}}
```

I tried this

```
$data_string['message']=1;
```

and it outputs this wrong object with the "1" in the beginning

```
1"dateDebut":"36000000","dateFin":"45000000","periodeDebut":"1410818400","periodeFin":"1411596000","jours":"Thursday","role":{"idRole":"1"},"zone":{"idzone":"Z1E2"},"tag":{"id":"511651969251"},"typeNotification":{"typeNotif":"Alerte"}}
```

even adding the field with quotes like this

```
$data_string['message']="1";
```

doesn't add the field message in the generated object json at all.

Comment: You can not add key-value pairs to a string. You need to `decode` the JSON string to an array, then add the key-value pair and `encode` it back to a JSON string.

Comment: Your already using `$data_string` as Json is no more PHP, so if you want `$data['message']=1;` and after that encode: `$data_string = json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant add data to the json string,  because its a string.

Add the data **before** you json encode it:

```
$data['message']=1;
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

Or if the original php object `$data` is out of scope by this point, you must decode to php object, add data and then encode back to json:

```
$data = json_decode($data_string);
$data['message']=1;
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do this:

```
$data_array = json_decode($data_string);
$data_array['message'] = 1;
$data_string = json_encode($data_array);
```

The string `$data_string` should contain the new member `message` with value 1;